# how to seperate dataframe by time in python?

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, time

Hi I am really new to python and your help will be really appreciated.

I have an excel data which has 4 variables.(time, digital, psi, BAR)

Time is from 13:25:00:00 to 14:25:00:00.(time goes up by 0.1 seconds, not 1 seconds)
I want to group 'bar' value by 2 minutes time so I can get maximum, minimum and average 'bar' value in each 2 minutes time.

I've tried to use this code:

```
 df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')
    
    df.time.resample('2T').min()
```

but it didn't help that much

can someone help me with this question? Thank you.

Comment: I would love to help you but there's not enough information in your question.
when you say it didn't help that much, what do you mean? 
Did it run but outputs are not what you expected? 
Did it report and error, if so, what's the error?
Please elaborate, also would be helpful if you put a sample of your input DataFrame, and your expected output.